# Navbar options not coming under header bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, navigationbar

Details : I am using bootstrap 3.3.6, trying to make my first navbar with bootstrap, a navbar which is collapsable on mobiles for better ui.

Problem : When the toggle button is clicked, the options are not displayed under the nav-brand but the first one is displayed next to the brand and the rest are below the first option.

e.g ->[image]

**I want the options to be stacked under the nav-brand "Dhruv Yadav"**.

index.html ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dhruv Yadav</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;font-family:'customfont',sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:30px;">Dhruv Yadav</a>
      <button id="navbtn" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
        <i style="color:white;" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navoptions">
        <li><a class="navoptions" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="navoptions" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="navoptions" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a class="navoptions" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card"></div>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.css ->

```
@font-face
{
font-family: "customfont";
src : url("AlexBrush-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
#navbar
{
background-color: #C00000;
}
#navbtn
{
 background-color : #C00000;
 border : 2px solid white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 height : 38px;
 }
#navbtn:hover
{
 transition : all 0.1s ease-in;
 background-color : #900000;
}
.card
{
  width : 100%;
  height : 400px;
  margin : 0 auto;
  background-color : white;
 }
 .navoptions
 {
  font-size : 17px;
  font-weight : 200;
  font-family : sans-serif;
  color : white;
 }
 .navoptions:hover
 {
  transition : all 0.25s ease-in;
  color : black;
 }
```

Thank You, any help received would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten wrapper to group brand and button:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;font-family:'customfont',sans-serif;font-weight:bold;font-size:30px;">Dhruv Yadav</a>
  <button id="navbtn" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
    <i style="color:white;" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/1bdomwfp/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use one div for nav-brand "Dhruv Yadav" and navbtn, and other for your navbar.

```
     <div> 
         <a> ... </a>
         <button> ... </button>
     </div>
         <div>
             ... navbar ...
         </div>
     </div>
```

Or you should combine nav-brand and navbar. Something like:

```
     <div> 
         <a> ... </a>
         <div>
             ... navbar ...
         </div>
     </div>
     <button> ... </button>
```